# Apache HttpClient - Log version of TLS that's negotiated in a request?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've got lots of code that uses Apache's HttpClient, and I'd like to log the version of TLS that's being negotiated when a request is made.

Is this possible?

I'd prefer an approach that doesn't requiring changing how the request is being built, if possible - something that inspects a response or views a log or something like that?

From my review, it appears this is only possible if we debug SSL at the VM level, or perhaps if a custom SSLContext is used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you turn on debug level logging for `org.apache.http.conn.ssl` category HttpClient will log quite a bit of details about the SSL session used including TLS/SSL protocol version.

```
[DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to httpbin.org/54.225.150.40:443
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to httpbin.org/54.225.150.40:443 with timeout 0
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Secure session established
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer principal: CN=httpbin.org
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  peer alternative names: [httpbin.org, www.httpbin.org]
[DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory -  issuer principal: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US
[DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 192.168.43.64:57534<->54.225.150.40:443
```

Comment: org.apache.http.conn.ssl does not seem to be present in the Apache HTTP Client present in Android. Could you please confirm the same? If yes, is there any alternative to get SSL logs?

Answer (score 1):

Also, another possibility is to create a custom `SSLContext` and get information from the opened sessions:

```java
    private static String URL = "https://www.google.com";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_FILE = "/Users/xpto/trust.p12";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_PASS = "truststore";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
    private static String TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(TRUST_STORE_FILE), TRUST_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore)
                .useProtocol(TLS_VERSION)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext))
                .build());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientFactory);

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        print("Requesting: " + URL);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        print("Response: " + response.getBody());

        printSSLContextInfo(sslContext);
    }

    private static void printSSLContextInfo(SSLContext sslContext) throws Exception {
        print("-------------\nPrinting TLS Client Information");
        SSLSessionContext sslSessionContext = sslContext.getClientSessionContext();
        Enumeration<byte[]> sessionIds = sslSessionContext.getIds();
        while (sessionIds.hasMoreElements()) {
            SSLSession sslSession = sslSessionContext.getSession(sessionIds.nextElement());
            print("Client: " + sslSession.getPeerHost() + ":" + sslSession.getPeerPort());
            print("\tProtocol: " + sslSession.getProtocol());
            print("\tSessionID: " + byteArrayToHex(sslSession.getId()));
            print("\tCipherSuite: " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
            for (X509Certificate certificate : sslSession.getPeerCertificateChain()) {
                print("\tX509 Certificate: " + certificate.getSubjectDN());
                print("\t\tIssuer: " + certificate.getIssuerDN().getName());
                print("\t\tAlgorithm: " + certificate.getSigAlgName());
                print("\t\tValidity: " + certificate.getNotAfter());
            }
        }
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
        for (byte b : a)
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void print(Object msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```

I'm just sharing this because I face similar issues, for further reference see: [How to obtain all TLS sessions from SSLContext using IBMJSSE2 default provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939309/how-to-obtain-all-tls-sessions-from-sslcontext-using-ibmjsse2-default-provider/68941812?noredirect=1#comment121850867_68941812)