# How to obtain all TLS sessions from SSLContext using IBMJSSE2 default provider?

Tags: java, security, ssl, websphere, tls1.2

I'm using as default provided for TLS connections the `IBMJSSEProvider2` and I have the following code to show information regarding the TLS sessions:

```java
SSLSessionContext sslSessionContext = SSLContext.getDefault().getClientSessionContext();
Enumeration<byte[]> sessionIds = sslSessionContext.getIds();
while (sessionIds.hasMoreElements()) {
  SSLSession sslSession = sslSessionContext.getSession(sessionIds.nextElement());
  writer.write("Client: " + sslSession.getPeerHost() + ":" + sslSession.getPeerPort() + "\n");
  writer.write("\tProtocol: " + sslSession.getProtocol() + "\n");
  writer.write("\tSessionID: " + byteArrayToHex(sslSession.getId()) + "\n");
  writer.write("\tCipherSuite: " + sslSession.getCipherSuite() + "\n");
  for (X509Certificate certificate : sslSession.getPeerCertificateChain()) {
    writer.write("\tX509 Certificate: " + certificate.getSubjectDN() + "\n");
    writer.write("\t\tIssuer: " + certificate.getIssuerDN().getName() + "\n");
    writer.write("\t\tAlgorithm: " + certificate.getSigAlgName() + "\n");
    writer.write("\t\tValidity: " + certificate.getNotAfter() + "\n");
  }
}
```

The code above is running on an instance of WebSphere 8.5. When I run this algorithm it doesn't print any information about the connections I had made to any HTTPS URLs using a `RestTemplate` implementation from Spring 3.2.
Using other providers like from Oracle shows the information. Am I missing something to make it work?

I'm trying to make a simple solution to troubleshoot which TLS versions are supported by a live instance of WebSphere. This is, of course, not recommended for live clients.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that, probably, the underlying libraries are not using the default context on WebSphere. Therefore, I had to create a custom client to make it using a specific SSLContext so I can list all the information I need. Following is the code to achieve this:

```java
    private static String URL = "https://www.google.com";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_FILE = "/Users/xpto/trust.p12";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_PASS = "truststore";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
    private static String TLS_VERSION = "TLSv1.2";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(TRUST_STORE_FILE), TRUST_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore)
                .useProtocol(TLS_VERSION)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext))
                .build());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientFactory);

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        print("Requesting: " + URL);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
        print("Response: " + response.getBody());

        printSSLContextInfo(sslContext);
    }

    private static void printSSLContextInfo(SSLContext sslContext) throws Exception {
        print("-------------\nPrinting TLS Client Information");
        SSLSessionContext sslSessionContext = sslContext.getClientSessionContext();
        Enumeration<byte[]> sessionIds = sslSessionContext.getIds();
        while (sessionIds.hasMoreElements()) {
            SSLSession sslSession = sslSessionContext.getSession(sessionIds.nextElement());
            print("Client: " + sslSession.getPeerHost() + ":" + sslSession.getPeerPort());
            print("\tProtocol: " + sslSession.getProtocol());
            print("\tSessionID: " + byteArrayToHex(sslSession.getId()));
            print("\tCipherSuite: " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
            for (X509Certificate certificate : sslSession.getPeerCertificateChain()) {
                print("\tX509 Certificate: " + certificate.getSubjectDN());
                print("\t\tIssuer: " + certificate.getIssuerDN().getName());
                print("\t\tAlgorithm: " + certificate.getSigAlgName());
                print("\t\tValidity: " + certificate.getNotAfter());
            }
        }
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
        for (byte b : a)
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void print(Object msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't include the TLS version in this or in any production code. Consider what will happen in 5-10 years' time when TLS 1.2 is obsolete.

Comment: Oh yeah, I agree with you. This code's purpose is for troubleshooting and not for live services. I'm facing some issues to understand why specific protocols are not working live for an instance of a legacy WebSphere.